# how to set all fields to mandatory fields in android app having two edittexts and one spinner

Tags: java, android

```
package com.example.dentalproject;



import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.EditTextPreference;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener 
{
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
EditText ettokenno,etcomments;
Button btnfeedback;
Spinner ratingspinner;
DatabaseAdapter dbAdapter;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    dbAdapter=new DatabaseAdapter(getApplicationContext());

    ettokenno=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.ed_tokennum);
    etcomments=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.ed_yourcomments);
    ratingspinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.sp1_select);
    btnfeedback=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnfeedback);


    btnfeedback.setOnClickListener(this);
}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
if(v.getId()==R.id.btnfeedback)
//if(ettokenno.equals("")&&(etcomments.equals("")))

{
//Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "save",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
String Tokenno=ettokenno.getText().toString();

String Comments=etcomments.getText().toString();


String Rating = ratingspinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

//String Rating = "Good";
if(Tokenno.equals(""))
{
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "please enter value",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
if(Comments.equals(""))
{
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "please enter value",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

dbAdapter.open();
long inserted=dbAdapter.insertTest(Tokenno,Comments, Rating);
if(inserted >0)
{
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "data saved",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

ettokenno.setText("");
etcomments.setText("");

}
else
{
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "data not saved",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
dbAdapter.close();
}
```

in this app i am having two edittexts and one spinner , how to restrict user to fill all fields and how to generate dialogue box when user leave the edit text and spinner with out filling data,  please help me friends thanks in advance
}
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is for two `TextView`'s

```
if (!text1.getText().toString().isEmpty() && !text2.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
     // Your Dialog or Toast for warning 
}
else{
     // your further code
}
```

and for `Spinner` you can set `setOnItemSelectedListener`

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            spinner.setSelection(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            spinner.setSelection(0);
        }
    });
```

Comment: when i am this my app shows error at getText , and the error is getText cannot be resolved or is not a field

Comment: its my mistake sorry...it should be text1.getText().toString()

Comment: and what is the methode for spinner plz help me

Comment: where to put above spinner methods in my code ,plz see my code and help me

Comment: put this method where you r going to check the details and will proceed further...i.e. onClick event of you button...and report me back

Answer (score 0):

Use a boolean variable, say, `flag`

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
if(v.getId()==R.id.btnfeedback)
//if(ettokenno.equals("")&&(etcomments.equals("")))

{
//Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "save",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
String Tokenno=ettokenno.getText().toString();

String Comments=etcomments.getText().toString();


String Rating = ratingspinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

boolean flag = true;
if(Tokenno.equals(""))
{
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "please enter value",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
flag = false;
}
if(Comments.equals(""))
{
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "please enter value",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
flag = false;
}

if(flag) {
dbAdapter.open();
long inserted=dbAdapter.insertTest(Tokenno,Comments, Rating);
if(inserted >0)
{
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "data saved",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

ettokenno.setText("");
etcomments.setText("");

}
else
{
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "data not saved",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
}
dbAdapter.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following code in your onClick

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(v.getId()==R.id.btnfeedback)
    {
    String Tokenno=ettokenno.getText().toString().trim();

    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(Tokenno)){
        //show dialog for Tokenno
        return;
    }
    String Comments=etcomments.getText().toString();
    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(Comments)){
        //show dialog for Comments
        return;
    }

    String Rating = ratingspinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

    if(Rating.equals("YOUR_DEFAULT_VALUE")){
        //show dialog for rating
        return;
    }

  //all fields are filled 
}
```

Here is [Tutorial](http://androidsolution4u.blogspot.in/2012/10/android-dialogs-tutorial-for-begginer.html) to display different types of dialogs